# How can I find if a letter following a symbol is in uppercase OR is another symbol using C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C# (and in coding in general), so I'm sorry if this question is silly.

I have to find if a letter following every / in this string is either an uppercase or another /.

```cs
string root = @"C:/File1/File2/File3/file1.txt"
```

And display the wrong character and its index:

```
if (Char.IsLower(root[c])) ;
{
Console.WriteLine("There is an error!");
Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLower(root[c]) + " is in lowercase!");
}
```

I tried with `Char.IsUpper()` and `str.IndexOf()` but I can't combine the strings and chars, and I don't know how to find the examinated character:

```
int at;
int startIndex = 0;
at = root.IndexOf("/", startIndex);
int c = at + 1;

if (Char.IsUpper(c));
```

Comment: Try `Char.IsUpper(root[c])`

Comment: Please edit it again, and add the code you use for "And display the wrong character and its index."

Comment: I didn't find anything for that because I wasn't able to find the previous solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the char at a given index in a string, you use the string index property:

```
char charAtCIndex = root[c];
```

So you can do

```
if(char.IsUpper(root[c]) || root[c]=='/')
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

It is a good practise though to check if the index if within the string length, as if the `/` is the last character of the string you'll get an Index out of range exception:

```
if(c < root.Length && (char.IsUpper(root[c]) || root[c]=='/'))
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have to show the error and the corresponding file now :D